# sql join and insert

Tags: sql

SQL newbie, I want to create a new table combining two tables. Im trying to use a insert select query to create a new table. so assuming the following

Jan Table

```
    C_ID      Total_Amount
      1           10
      2            3
      3            5
```

Feb Table

```
    C_ID      Total_Amount
     1            4
     4            22
     5            6
```

I want Final table

```
    C_ID       Jan_Amount          Feb_Amount
     1             10                  4
     2             3                   0
     3             5                   0
     4             0                   22
     5             0                   6
```

My SQL statement is

```
insert into Final 
    select Jan.C_ID, Jan.Total_Amount, Feb.Total_amount
    from Jan 
    full outer join Feb on Jan.C_ID = Feb.C_ID
```

The problem is that when I do `select Jan.C_ID`, it will not include customer id 4 and 5 from the Feb table.

What is the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  You have enough points on the site that you should know not put on unrelated tags.

Comment: @user187 do you have a table that contains all possible `C_ID`s?

Answer (score 2):

you could join the tables alos using a union all eg:

```
  insert into Final 
  select C_ID, ifnull(jan_Total_Amount,0), ifnull(feb_Total_amount,0)f
  from (

  select Jan.C_ID, Jan.Total_Amount as jan_Total_Amount, null as feb_Total_amount
  from jan
  union all
  select fed.C_ID, null, feb.Total_Amount
  from feb
    ) t
```

And for obtain the two value for the same C_ID you could use a (fake) aggrgation function and group by

```
  insert into Final 
  select C_ID, min(jan_Total_Amount), feb_Total_amount
  from (
  select C_ID, ifnull(jan_Total_Amount,0) jan_Total_Amount , ifnull(feb_Total_amount,0) feb_Total_amount
  from (

  select Jan.C_ID, Jan.Total_Amount as jan_Total_Amount, null as feb_Total_amount
  from jan
  union all
  select fed.C_ID, null, feb.Total_Amount
  from feb
    ) t
  )t2 
  group by C_ID
```

Comment: Will that merge the 2 rows that both have a `C_ID` of `1`?

Comment: Yea to @Terminus point will this join rows that have the same C_ID?

Comment: Answer  updated  with a suggestion for the values of the same C_ID

Comment: And how I incorporate more months such as March? I have to join tables across multiple months/yrs and with this method I think the query will blow up real fast? no

Answer (score 0):

You could apply `left join` and `right join` with `Union`

```
insert into Table_3 (C_ID,Jan_Amount, Feb_Amount)
select T1.C_ID,T1.Total_Amount, T2.Total_Amount from Jan T1 left join Feb T2 ON T1.C_ID = T2.C_ID
UNION
select T2.C_ID,T1.Total_Amount, T2.Total_Amount from Jan T1 right join Feb T2 ON T1.C_ID = T2.C_ID
where T1.C_ID is null
```

Comment: insert into Table_3 (CID,Jan_Amount, Feb_Amount, March_Amount)
select T1.CID,T1.Total_Amount, T2.Total_Amount, T3.Total_Amount from Jan T1 left join Feb T2 ON T1.CID = T2.CID left join March T3 on T1.CID = T3.CID 
UNION
select T2.CID,T1.Total_Amount, T2.Total_Amount, T3.Total_Amount from Jan T1 right join Feb T2 ON T1.CID = T2.CID left join March T3 on T2.CID = T3.CID 
where T1.CID and T3.CID is null
UNION
select T3.CID,T1.Total_Amount, T2.Total_Amount, T3.Total_Amount from Jan T1 right join March T3 ON T1.CID = T3.CID left join Feb T2 on T3.CID = T2.CID 
where T1.CID and T2.CID is null

Comment: sorry I overwrote my explanation when I copy and pasted.
I was wondering if I want to expand it into march do I use the above query then?